# Multiple websites with one IP: settings with proxy server and proxy cache (flask, uwsgi, nginx)

Tags: caching, nginx, reverse, uwsgi, proxy-server

I want to allow my nginx server to server multiple subdomains.
Each site is served by a flask + uwsgi, listening to own ports.

All sites have many endpoints with same name, and responses are cached in different zones: I want to serve the correct cache (or correct site) from the proxy server.

I read https://askubuntu.com/questions/766352/multiple-websites-on-nginx-one-ip : in my configuration I keep having domain2 redirected to domain1.
I cannot find proper configuration for listening to uwsgi and have the proxy server serve the correct site.

**How to properly set the ports and proxy_cache on the proxy_server to allow nginx serve two flask sites from a single server?**

Below is my set current setup:

**configuration domain_1**

```
server {        
    server_name www.domain1.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 8000 default_server;
    server_name domain1.com;

    root /var/www/example_site_1;

    # common locations for all sites
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/example_site_1/domain1.sock;
    }

    # API
    location /api {                     
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT wsgi;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/example_site_1/domain1.sock;
    }
}



# Set cache directory for site

proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx/domain1 levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone_domain_1:10m max_size=50m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";


# Virtualhost/server configuration
server {
    listen  80  default_server;
    server_name domain1;

    root /var/www/domain1;

    ## how to serve proxy_cache if locations of domain_1 and domain_2 are the same ?

    location / {        
        proxy_cache my_zone_domain_1;    
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://domain1.com:8000;
    }

    location /api {
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_cache my_zone_domain_1;
        proxy_pass http://domain1.com:8000/api;
    }

}
```

**configuration domain_2**

```
server {        
    server_name www.domain2.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 3000;
    server_name domain2.com;

    root /var/www/example_site_2;

    # common locations for all sites
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/example_site_2/domain2.sock;
    }

    # API
    location /api {                     
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT wsgi;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/example_site_2/domain2.sock;
    }
}



# Set cache directory for site

proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx/domain2 levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone_domain_2:10m max_size=50m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";


# Virtualhost/server configuration
server {

    # I tried listening on other ports than 80, but kept having redirects on domain_1     

    listen  80;
    server_name domain2;

    root /var/www/domain2;

    ## how to serve proxy_cache if locations of domain_1 and domain_2 are the same ?

    location / {        
        proxy_cache my_zone_domain_2;    
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://domain2.com:3000;
    }

    location /api {
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_cache my_zone_domain_2;
        proxy_pass http://domain2.com:3000/api;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your domain_2 configuration uses `proxy_pass http://domain2.com:8000` but there is only domain_1 server listens on the port 8000 so it gets to serve requests directed to domain_2.

I also recommend you to rethink usage of proxy_pass in your configuration, it isn't really necessary.

Comment: my typo: proxy_pass for location /api listen on two distinct doors (3000 and 8000), but it still redirect domain_2 to domain_1. 
Could you elaborate on rethink usage of proxy_pass ? 
My use case is to cache GET APIs with response 200 for endpoints like domain.com/entity/one (leaving out domain.com/entity?q=one) - and avoid conflicts between domain_1 and domain_2, since apis carries the same name.
Would you like to post an example?

Comment: Another issue with domain2 configuration for port 80 is that `server_name domain2;` won't match requests to `domain2.com`, these requests will be handled by the server section with `server_name domain1 default_server;' as it has `default_server` option. You don't need `proxy_pass` as you can use `uwsgi_pass` instead in the server section which listens on the port 80, just use `uwsgi_cache` instead of `proxy_cache`.

Comment: Not working: I removed default_server from configuration domain_1, in the first server block. Now `server { listen  8000; server_name domain1; ... }` , `server { listen  3000; server_name domain2; ... }` and  `server { listen  80;  domain1; }` and   `server { listen  80; domain2; }` I tried also the latter listen to port 8080 but no success : `curl localhost:3000/api` keeps on redirecting on port 8000.

Comment: Your issue is that domain2 != domain2.com

Comment: thanks for helping alex, I set correct extension on server_names.
I tried to make server blocks for domain1 and domain2 listen to both 80 and 8080, and set default_server for each as described in the guide : 
`It is possible to define servers listening on ports *:80 and *:8080, and direct that one will be the default server for port *:8080, while the other will be the default for port *:80` but did not work out. Are you available for a chat to help fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145657/discussion-between-user305883-and-alexd).

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit was Uwsgi : it was loaded from `usr/bin` folder, and not from virtual environment folder of my app.

Maybe virtualenv folder was corrupted: when I tried to re-install uwsgi (`pip install uwsgi`), it kept saying requirements satisfied until I noticed that `which uwsgi` was not loaded from virtualenv.

I had to remove and reinstall virtualenv folder with uwsgi and python modules.

Now applications were running (answer to the question), but proxy_server configuration has to be further adjusted in my case.

The following may be useful for people making use of `url_for()` directives in flask: `url_for()` directive routes to an absolute path, which may conflict with the nginx proxy.

Example: nginx proxy server listens on domains2.com on port 80, proxy_pass `/path` location to `http://domain2.com:3000`; if flask is redirecting a route to `/path` (with `url_for()`), the resulting url will be `http://domain2.com:3000/path` (because it follows the port specified in absolute path) instead of `http://domain2.com/path` (the url of the proxy).

Add `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` to `/path` location to allow nginx proxy follow the correct redirect of your flask application.